# Вывод ошибок Yii2 во всплывающих дивах

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, yii2, pjax

Есть задача, сделать вывод ошибок во всплывающих дивах
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно выводить ошибки в тех блоках которые на фотке.
Допустим человек заполнил форму и допустил ошибку, эта ошибка должна появится не возле вводимого поля как это реализовано стандартным механизмом, а во всплывающем окне.
Кто знает как это сделать?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Мне было бы лень лезть в php и я бы сделал небольшой скрипт на js, который будет переносить ошибки из формы во всплывающее окно.

```
function popupErrors(container) {
    var src = $('form', container),
        dst = $('.popup', container);

  dst.append($('.error', src));
}

popupErrors($(document));
```

popupErrors() можно запустить после загрузки странички, либо после того как придет ajax ответ и вы вставите его на страничку.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e1ugzzgb/)

Comment: не подходит, нужно переопределить вывод как-то=(

Comment: @Ricco381 вы пользуетесь ActiveForm?

Comment: да, только свой но на основе ActiveForm

Comment: ошибки валидации модели находятся внутри модели - их можно получить через $model->errors и отрендерить внутри своей всплывающей вьюхи (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activerecord.html). Чтобы ошибок не было видно рядом с полями я бы скрыл их через css, Но если хотите чтобы они в принципе не выводились, то надо рендерить форму руками (тут и в коментах есть примеры различные https://toster.ru/q/76516)

Answer (score 1):

Я пользовался yii2-noty, вполне удобно, можно в любом углу выводить сообщения, разных цветов, красота.